# Cloud functions - update data in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud functions to count how many comments there are on a post.
When i add a comment it saves it in the firebase database and then on Cloud functions there is a functions that listen to "Comments" node and should "+1" back to firebase database.

For some reason it works only when i delete the comment from firebase database.
when i delete the comment its add "+1".

**Thats my code**

```
    exports.commentsCount = functions.database.ref('/comments/{commentid}/{userUID}').onWrite(event =>{
const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
const model = event.data.previous.val();
const commentid = event.params.commentid;

console.log("commentID:",commentid);

const countComments = collectionRef.child('countComments');


return countComments.transaction(current => {
  console.log('Before the If');
  if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
    console.log('Enter to the if.');
    const commentsList = admin.database().ref(`comments/${commentid}/countComments`).transaction(current => {
      return (current || 0) + 1;
    });
  }
}).then(() => {
      console.log('Comments counter updated.');
         });  
    });
```

Anyone can tell me where im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're using this to determine when your function gets triggered:

```
exports.commentsCount = functions.database.ref('/comments/{commentid}/{userUID}').onWrite(event =>{
```

Key here is that you use `onWrite`, which means that this function gets triggered for *any* write operation under `/comments/{commentid}/{userUID}`.

Since you're only adding to the count, your function should only run when a new comment is added. For that you should use `onCreate` instead of `onWrite`:

```
exports.commentsCount = functions.database.ref('/comments/{commentid}/{userUID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
  const collectionRef = snapshot.ref.parent;
  const model = snapshot.val();
  const commentid = context.params.commentid;
```

I also updated the parameters to match with the 1.0 Firebase Functions library. See the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) for more on that.